# Why aren't these the same

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why don't these two have the same result. The purpose of this function is to replace the value of s(x) with a defined string(y). This is purely to understand/ practice using functions.

```
s = "a"

def func(x,y):
    x = x.replace(x,y)
    print(s)

func(s,"b")
```

and

```
s = "a"
s = s.replace(s,"b")
print(s)
```

Comment: what are the results?

Comment: Because `x = ...` assigns a value to `x`. It has nothing to do with `s`.

Comment: @zondo If I type s into the function after defining it would x not represent s?

Comment: @MCMastery a for the first, b for the second

Comment: you are printing 's' in the function if you print 'x' result will be as desired

Comment: `s` is a name for a value. It isn't a value itself. So no, you can't say `x = s` and expect the two variables to be exactly equivalent. They merely refer to the same object. When you then reassign `x`, those two variables no longer refer to the same object. It does nothing to `s`.

Comment: @zondo So when I type s into the function it treats x as "a" or does it not work at all?

Comment: The point of a variable is to evaluate to something. So yes, `x = s` means to evaluate `s`, which is `"a"`, and then assign `x` to it. So now `x` and `s` are two names for the same object, `"a"`. When you then say `x = ` something else, you are now assigning the name to another object. It does nothing to any other names. `s` has no reason to be reassigned.

Comment: @zondo So what's happening in the second one that it works and why is it different?

Comment: In the second one, you are dealing with only one variable. It starts out as one object and is then reassigned to another. When you print it, it shows the second value. If in the first, you had said `print(x)`, like Daniele's answer, it would be directly equivalent to the second.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to print `x` inside the `func` function instead of `s`. You find out that you're printing the same value.

```
s = "a"

def func(x,y):
    x = x.replace(x,y)
    print(x)

func(s,"b") # prints 'b'

s = "a"
s = s.replace(s, "b")
print(s)    # prints 'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in Python. `replace()` doesn't modify the string it was given, it returns a new string. So when you do:

```
x = x.replace(x, y)
```

in the first function, it's creating a new string and assigning that to the local variable `x`. The string in the original variable `s` is not affected.

Also, function parameters are passed by value, not by reference. So assigning to `x` in the function doesn't assign to the outer variable `s`.